# Service Fabric Should i put cluster connection informtion into my publish profile for OnPrem?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

What I'm attempting to do is call this publish profile from Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1 locally to push the App to the cluster.

If I perform a Get-ServiceFabricClusterConnection I get the results below.  My understanding is that I should use that information in my publish profile to choose a connection to a cluster.  If so what items should I use?  Most examples are for Azure only.

```
ConnectionEndpoint   : 
FabricClientSettings : {
                   ClientFriendlyName                   : PowerShell-06442d85-7b51-40d0-8859-3ac9551c7363
                   PartitionLocationCacheLimit          : 100000
                   PartitionLocationCacheBucketCount    : 1024
                   ServiceChangePollInterval            : 00:02:00
                   ConnectionInitializationTimeout      : 00:00:02
                   KeepAliveInterval                    : 00:00:20
                   ConnectionIdleTimeout                : 00:00:00
                   HealthOperationTimeout               : 00:02:00
                   HealthReportSendInterval             : 00:00:00
                   HealthReportRetrySendInterval        : 00:00:30
                   NotificationGatewayConnectionTimeout : 00:00:30
                   NotificationCacheUpdateTimeout       : 00:00:30
                   AuthTokenBufferSize                  : 4096
                   }
GatewayInformation   : {
                   NodeAddress                          : {myBox}.{MyDomain}.net:19000
                   NodeId                               : 85772935593a0315f92e3293832c5fe9
                   NodeInstanceId                       : 131303949240153844
                   NodeName                             : vm0
                   }
PSComputerName       : {mybox}.{mydomain}.net

ConnectionEndpoint   : 
FabricClientSettings : {
                   ClientFriendlyName                   : PowerShell-06442d85-7b51-40d0-8859-3ac9551c7363
                   PartitionLocationCacheLimit          : 100000
                   PartitionLocationCacheBucketCount    : 1024
                   ServiceChangePollInterval            : 00:02:00
                   ConnectionInitializationTimeout      : 00:00:02
                   KeepAliveInterval                    : 00:00:20
                   ConnectionIdleTimeout                : 00:00:00
                   HealthOperationTimeout               : 00:02:00
                   HealthReportSendInterval             : 00:00:00
                   HealthReportRetrySendInterval        : 00:00:30
                   NotificationGatewayConnectionTimeout : 00:00:30
                   NotificationCacheUpdateTimeout       : 00:00:30
                   AuthTokenBufferSize                  : 4096
                   }
GatewayInformation   : {
                   NodeAddress                          : {MyBox}.{MyDomain}.net:19000
                   NodeId                               : 85772935593a0315f92e3293832c5fe9
                   NodeInstanceId                       : 131303949240153844
                   NodeName                             : vm0
                   }
PSComputerName       : {myBox}.{myDomian}.net
```

Thanks, 
Greg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just the endpoint and any authentication you are using:

e.g.

```
<ClusterConnectionParameters ConnectionEndpoint="{myBox}.{MyDomain}.net:19000" WindowsCredentials="true" ServerCertThumbprint="0123456789012345678901234567890123456789" />
```